# How to communicate between Android, IOS device and SUNMI v2s printer throw NFC using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, nfc, wallet, google-wallet, sunmi

i'm trying to write a flutter code that can be installed on sumni v2s printer, the basic idea is i want to make this android device (SUNMI v2s) read the NFC data from android or apple phone and extract ehe transferred data, this data should be extracted from Google wallet pass or Apple pass.

Additional information:
Based in SUNMI website it has these NFC specs -> Mifare/Felica/ISO 14443 typ A/B IS15693.

I have successfully created the Google/Apple pass using Php.

how can we implement this feature using flutter framework?

I expect that when i get close to SUNMI printer with My wallet opened i can get the information of the wallet pass or just i might see a notification that the Event ticket pass is successfully activated.

I don't want to post any code because it's useless, it's just o copy of how to read/write tags using **nfc_manager ** package i found https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager.

Comment: You will need access to the Google Smart Tap Specification as well as the NFC encryption keys and collector ID for each Google Wallet pass that you want to read.  For Apple, you will need their VAS specification and details of the PassTypeID certificate used to sign the pass.  Both specs are only available under NDA, so I can't help with specifics.  Both also require modifications to the NFC polling loop to be able to present NFC passes on the lock screen.  I cannot see that SUNMI have implemented either of these specs.

Comment: @PassKit If i used PassKit, Do i need to do all this hustle? or you have google and apple part covered form your side? so that i used Sunmi as my NFC reader? And I have also order Janam device to test NFC reading.

Comment: Unfortunately creating passes is easy - it's reading them that is not.  The hardware needs the necessary APIs to configure the pass parameters it needs to present the pass, conduct a dialogue with the phone to read it, and decrypt the payload.  The only thing we can help with is a decryption API for encrypted payloads but this will not be of use for an NFC device that has not implemented the Google SmartTap and Apple VAS protocols.  For devices, we recommend ID Tech (https://idtechproducts.com) or V-Tap (https://www.vtapnfc.com) readers.

Comment: The Janam XT3 specs state "Optional support for Apple Value Added  Services (VAS) and Enhanced Contactless  Polling (ECP) and Google Smart Tap" so you may have more luck with that.